# How to find out xmlrpc interface of any webservice?

Tags: web-services, xml-rpc, xmlrpclib

How to find out xmlrpc interface of any webservice? For example in case of SOAP webservices you can just have a look at WSDL and findout the interface. In particular I am looking for interface of xmlrpc implemented using xmlrpclib in python. I have souce code of server available, which file should I look for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to do this. XML/RPC is not self-describing.